# Find duplicate values from user input in Python

Tags: python

My initial code was a basic calculator in Python 2.7.8 but I have now decided I would like to include a function where the user can enter multiple values.

Once this has been entered the function can run with the values the user just entered stored into a variable (function parameters) then get told whether they entered duplicate values or not For now the values get split at the commas and are inserted into a list and the function runs.

I have created a function which already takes the variables equal to the user input of 'AlgorithmListEntry' which happens when the user types algorithm.

```
def findDuplicates(AlgorithmListEntry):
                for i in len(range(AlgorithmListEntry)):
                    for j in len(1,range(AlgorithmListEntry)):
                        if AlgorithmListEntry[i]==AlgorithmListEntry[j]:
                            return True
                return False
```

Where the function looks for the range of the parameter as well but this did not work because of another error

```
for i in len(range(AlgorithmListEntry)):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.
```

I am now receiving an error

```
for i in len(AlgorithmListEntry):TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

For ease of viewing I have only inserted the part of the code which is relevant to my question

```
i = True #starts outer while loop
j = True #inner scientific calculations loop

def findDuplicates(AlgorithmListEntry):
            for i in len(AlgorithmListEntry):
                for j in len(1(AlgorithmListEntry)):
                    if AlgorithmListEntry[i]==AlgorithmListEntry[j]:
                        return True
            return False


while i==True:
    UserInput=raw_input('Please enter the action you want to do: add/sub or Type algorithm for something special: ')
    scienceCalc=('Or type other to see scientific calculations')

    if UserInput=='algorithm':
        listEntry=raw_input('Please enter numbers to go in a list:').split(",")
        AlgorithmListEntry = list(listEntry)
        print AlgorithmListEntry
        print "The program will now try to find duplicate values within the values given"

        findDuplicates(AlgorithmListEntry)
    #i = False
```

**Questions**

1. Why am I receiving both of these errors?
2. What can I do to successfully implement this function into my program? So that the user can receive feedback on whether the values they entered contained duplicate values?

Comment: Doh, you really need to clean up your code, with respect to PEP8, before hoping that many people are willing to read through that. Seriously, work on your indentation, and camelcase for a name bound to a list as in `AlgorithmListEntry = list(listEntry)` is horrible :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing `len(range(foo))` instead of `range(len(foo))`

`range` looks like this:

```
range(end)              --> [0, 1, 2, ..., end-1]
range(start, end)       --> [start, start+1, ..., end-1]
range(start, end, step) --> [start, start+step, start+step*2, ..., end-1]
```

`len` gives the length of a sequence, so `len([1,2,3,4,5])` is `5`.

`len(range([1,2,3]))` breaks because `range` can't accept a list as an argument.

`len([1,2,3])` breaks because it returns the length of the list as an integer, which isn't iterable. That makes your line look like:

```
for i in 3:  # TypeError!
```

Instead you want to make a range of as many numbers as there are elements in `AlgorithmListEntry`.

```
for i in range(len(AlgorithListEntry)):
    # do stuff
```